# Get combined data from table

Tags: mysql

I have the folling problem I didn't get solved for days.

I have 3 tables.

Table "Distributor"

```
ID | Distributor
1 | Distributor A
2 | Distributor B
3 | Distributor C
```

Table "Product":

```
ID | Product
1 | Apple
2 | Peache
3 | Banana
4 | Lemon
```

Table "DistributorProduct" - which Distributor can deliver which Product.

```
ID | DistributorID | ProductID
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 1 | 3
4 | 1 | 4
5 | 2 | 1
6 | 2 | 3
7 | 2 | 4
7 | 3 | 3
7 | 4 | 4
```

Now I want to get all Distributors which can deliver Apple AND Banana. (the result must be Distributor A and Distributor B).

How can I do this? What is the SQL-Statement?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Dieter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.* 
from Distributor d
left join DistributorProducts dp on dp.DistributorId = d.id
left join Product p on p.Id = dp.ProductId and p.product = 'Apple' and     
p.product = 'Banana'
```

If some join expression error then you can do without joins.

```
select d.*
from Distributor d, DistributorProducts dp, Product p
where dp.DistributorId = d.id
and p.Id = dp.ProductId
and (p.product = 'Apple' AND p.product = 'Banana');
```

I am sure this should work.

Comment: That don't work.
Error Message: "JOIN expression not supported"

Comment: @derdieter: updated with another solution. check it.

Comment: Wir your solution I get an empty result. The problem seems to be the second "AND".
Without "and p.product = 'Banana';" I get all results with "Apple". but with both ANDs ('Apple' AND 'Banana') there are no results.

Comment: Yes I got it. 
Check now

Comment: This gives me all Distributors that sell Apples and all Distributors that sell Bananas. But I need only the Distributors which can sell both.

Comment: then you need to change OR into AND

Comment: AND gives no result (empty result)

Comment: send me your schema at `ping@naveedramzan.com` I will check and send you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select Distributor.ID, Distributor.Name
from Distributor, Product Apple, Product Banana, DistributorProduct
where
    DistributorProduct.DistributorID = Distributor.ID and
    DistributorProduct.ProductID = Apple.ID and
    Apple.Name = 'Apple' and
    DistributorProduct.ProductID = Banana.ID and
    Banana.Name = 'Banana'
group by Distributor.ID
```

Comment: what do you men with "Product Apple, Product Banana" in the FROM term?
And what is Apple.Name?

Comment: It's short alias form for "Product as Apple"Apple

Comment: So Apple.Name is Product.Name, i use two copies of Product here, one filtered by Name = 'Apple' and second by Name = 'Banana'